How can I observe changes to a model in SwiftUI using a ViewModel with SwiftData?
I am working on a SwiftUI macOS application. My goal is to observe changes in my model using a ViewModel to update the UI accordingly. However, my MenuView does not observe changes when I add a new data to SwiftData.
Expected Results:
I expect that when I add a new project data, the MenuView updates automatically to reflect the new project in the items array.
Actual Results:
Instead, the MenuView only reflects changes on initialization and does not update when a new project is added to SwiftData.
What I've Tried:
I have tried initializing the viewModel in the init method of MenuView. The initialization works perfectly, but it seems that the MenuView does not observe changes after initialization.
I have searched for solutions on Stack Overflow and reviewed the SwiftUI documentation, but none of the solutions I found have worked for my specific case.
Code:
Here is the minimum amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem:
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct MenuView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Environment(\.openWindow) var openWindow
    
    @StateObject var viewModel: MenuViewModel = MenuViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(viewModel.items, id: \.id) { item in
                Menu(item.title) {
                    EnvironmentsMenuView(environments: item.environments) {
                        do {
                            modelContext.delete(item.project)
                            
                            try modelContext.save()
                        } catch {
                            print("Failed to clear all projects data.")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Divider()
            Button(action: addProject) {
                Text("Add Project")
            }
            Divider()
            Button("Delete Projects") {
                do {
                    try modelContext.delete(model: ProjectStack.self)
                    try modelContext.delete(model: Project.self)
                    
                    try modelContext.save()
                    try viewModel.fetchItems()
                } catch {
                    print("Failed to clear all projects data.")
                }
            }
            Button("Exit") {
                NSApplication.shared.terminate(nil)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.setModelContext(modelContext)
            
            do {
                try viewModel.fetchItems()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func addProject() {
        do {
            let descriptor = FetchDescriptor<DAEnvironment>()
            let environments = try modelContext.fetch(descriptor)
            
            if environments.isEmpty {
                print("Environments is empty")
            } else {
                print("Environments is not empty")
            }
            
            Project.add(with: openWindow)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

class MenuViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [MenuItem] = []
    
    var modelContext: ModelContext?
    
    func setModelContext(_ modelContext: ModelContext) {
        self.modelContext = modelContext
    }
    
    func fetchItems() throws {
        guard let modelContext = self.modelContext else {
            throw MenuViewModelError.modelContextNotFound
        }
        
        do {
            let descriptor = FetchDescriptor<Project>()
            let projects = try modelContext.fetch(descriptor)
            
            for project in projects {
                var commandsByEnvironment: [DAEnvironment: Command] = Dictionary()
                
                for command in project.commands ?? [] {
                    if let environment = command.environment {
                        if commandsByEnvironment[environment] == nil {
                            commandsByEnvironment[environment] = command
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                let menuEnvironmentItems: [MenuEnvironmentItem] = commandsByEnvironment.map { (environment, command) in
                    return MenuEnvironmentItem(
                        id: environment.slug ?? "",
                        title: environment.name ?? "",
                        command: command,
                        projectId: project.id
                    )
                }
                
                let menuItem = MenuItem(
                    title: project.title,
                    environments: menuEnvironmentItems,
                    project: project
                )
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.items.append(menuItem)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Cannot fetch projects")
        }
    }
}

How can I observe changes to the model in the ViewModel to update the items array in MenuView when a new project is added?

In SwiftUI the View structs are the view model already so just use that. It’s @Query for swift data. Also it’s best to let the auto-save handle saving so it’s done at the right time.

I found a solution, but i dont know if is the best one... its creating a observer to NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange, follow the code:
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    forName: .NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange,
    object: nil,
    queue: .main
) { _ in
    do {
        try self.fetchItems()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

